# Retrieve VSTS/TFS Build task name list

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need to retrieve build task name list from VSTS/TFS build. Is there inbuilt method/library available to support this?

I have already noted (as below sample) that we can retrieve same in release.

```
import ReleaseClient = require("ReleaseManagement/Core/RestClient");
var rc= ReleaseClient.getClient(); 

release.environments.forEach(function (env) { 
    rc.getTasks(VSS.getWebContext().project.id, release.id, env.id).then(function(taskList){
    ...............
    ......Some code here
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/build/restclient/buildhttpclient2_2) doesn't show a direct function call to retrieve the tasks. However, there is a contract for a [`BuildDefinition`](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/build/contracts/builddefinition), which contains a `build` property, which is an array of [`BuildDefinitionStep`](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/build/contracts/builddefinitionstep), each of which has a `task` property that contains things like the name of the task and the inputs.

The [`getDefinition()`](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/build/restclient/buildhttpclient2_2#method_getDefinition) function should give you back a build definition you can work with.

```
import RestClient = require("TFS/Build/RestClient");

// Get an instance of the client
var client = RestClient.getClient();
var myDefinition client.getDefinition(1234);
```

Comment: HI @Daniel Mann, Thanks for your response. Following your guidelines we were able to get build definition as following. But build contract definition dosen't have a build property to get build BuildDefinitionStep 
//Code start//
client.getDefinition(build.definition.id).then((buildContractDefinition) => {
  
});//Code end//

Comment: @Lalindu It works fine for me. Specify the project argument for getDefinition method and try again.