# Retrieve the list of Tasks for Build Definition using .NET client libraries for VSTS/TFS

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using the .NET client libraries for VSTS/TFS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=vsts) to retrieve a list of tasks for all Build Definitions for all Team Projects. I'm using the v16.139.0-preview version of the NuGet package Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ExtendedClient (I need to because I need to retrieve Release Definition workflow as well for which you need Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Release.Client which has a dependency requirement for the ExtendedClient). The server (on-prem) is a TFS 2017.2. In no way I'm able to retrieve the tasks/phases/process. This is my code:

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection"), new VssClientCredentials());
ProjectHttpClient projectClient = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
IEnumerable<TeamProjectReference> projects = projectClient.GetProjects().Result;
BuildHttpClient buildClient = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
foreach (var project in projects)
{
  IPagedList<BuildDefinition> buildDefinitions = buildClient.GetFullDefinitionsAsync2(project: project.Name, name: null).Result;
  foreach (BuildDefinition buildDefinition in buildDefinitions)
  {
    // get the tasks
  }
}
```

- I have tried to re-retrieve the Build Definition using buildClient.GetDefinitionAsync without additional effect
- The "Steps" property (which is going to be deprecated) is always null
- The "Process" property is empty
- There is no "phases" property available (which seems logical looking at the options to have multiple phases in a Build Definition
- There is a contract available for BuildDefinitionStep: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/reference/client/api/tfs/build/contracts/builddefinitionstep?view=vsts
- The REST API documentation doesn't have a property called "Step": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/definitions/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1#builddefinition

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @Andy I was able to solve the problem. I used Fiddler call the REST Api (http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_apis/build/definitions/1) and read the JSON response. I discovered that the "build" property contains the collection of tasks. I fixed the PowerShell script provided by @Andy:

```
Param(
   [string]$baseurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection", 
   [string]$projectName = "MyProject",
   [string]$buildDefinitionID = "530",
   [string]$user = "domain\user",
   [string]$token = "PersonalAccessToken"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$uri = "$baseurl/$($projectName)/_apis/build/definitions/$buildDefinitionID"
Write-Host $uri
$result = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})

foreach ($task in $result.build)
{
    Write-Host $task.displayName
}
```

Comment: So this is currently only possible via REST-Api, not via client library?
The "Steps" property was filled in version 15.112.1 of the client libraries, but it is always null in version 15.131.1 :(

Answer (score 2):

Just try below C# sample using .NET client libraries, test on **TFS 2017.3** and **VSTS**, both work. (No TFS 2017.2 on my side, If I remember correctly, TFS 2017.2 has the similar build process with TFS 2015, It has no the "`Process`" and "`phases`" attribute. )

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;

namespace RetrieveTaskList
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //For TFS :
            var tfsUrl = "http://ws-tfs2017:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection";
            var buildClient = new BuildHttpClient(new Uri(tfsUrl), new VssAadCredential());

            //For VSTS:
            //var tfsUrl = "https://{account}.visualstudio.com";
            //var buildClient = new BuildHttpClient(new Uri(tfsUrl), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "PAT here"));

            var definitions = buildClient.GetFullDefinitionsAsync(project: "ScrumProject");

            foreach (var definition in definitions.Result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\n {0} - {1}:", definition.Id, definition.Name));

                // Get BuildDefinitionStep to array, each of which has a task property that contains things like the name of the task and the inputs.
                var tasks = definition.Steps.ToArray();

                //Get each step/task from the array
                foreach (var task in tasks)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(task.DisplayName);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

You can also use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/previous-apis/build/definitions?view=tfs-2018#get-a-build-definition) to retrieve the list of tasks from a build definition.

PowerShell for example:

```
Param(
   [string]$baseurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection", 
   [string]$projectName = "ProjectName",
   [string]$buildDefinitionID = "26",
   [string]$user = "domain\user",
   [string]$token = "password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))


$uri = "$baseurl/$($projectName)/_apis/build/definitions/$buildDefinitionID"
Write-Host $uri
$result = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})
$tasks = $result.process.phases.steps.displayName

foreach ($task in $tasks)
{
  write-host $task
}
```

[image]

You can also try the REST Client, please reference this thread : [Retrieve VSTS/TFS Build task name list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218224/retrieve-vsts-tfs-build-task-name-list)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andy. I know I can use the REST API, but I specifically asked for a solution using the client libraries. From you answer I assume that it is not possible to use the client libraries in this case?

Comment: One more note, I ran the script you provided as-is, but `$result.process` remains `$null`. Maybe you overlooked the TFS version I provided?

Comment: @Fokko If I remember correctly, TFS 2017.2 has the similar build process with TFS 2015, It has no the "`Process`" and "`phases`" attribute. You can check the attributes from the response of the REST API. See the updated answer with .NET client libraries....

Comment: @Fokko Have you resolved the issue by the updated answer? any update?

Comment: I'm sorry, I will not be at the customer I'm helping with this issue until next week. Will post an update by then.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't work on my environment. The first example using the .NET client libraries doesn't work because the "steps" property is always "null". The second example doesn't work because the "process" property is always "null".

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but if you're wanting to iterate over the Build tasks using the AzDO .NET Client library you need to cast the Process to a DesignerProcess/DockerProcess/YamlProcess.

```
var buildDefinitions = await _buildClient.GetFullDefinitionsAsync(project.Id);
foreach (var buildDefinition in buildDefinitions)
{
    if (buildDefinition.Process != null && buildDefinition.Process is Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.DesignerProcess designerProcess)
    {
        foreach (var phase in designerProcess.Phases)
            foreach (var step in phase.Steps)
                Console.WriteLine($"taskname={step.DisplayName}");
        break;//lets exit the loop early
    }
}
```

Demo repo, https://github.com/f2calv/azdo-api-net-client-issue