# Can I add to a Pipeline Triggers 'Branch Filters' list through the API

Tags: c#, api, azure-devops, triggers, azure-pipelines

Hope you can help!

New to Azure DevOps API but I simply want to be able to update the list of Branch Filters under a Pipelines trigger through the API.

[image]

Does such an API Method exist and if not, has anyone successfully managed to do this and how?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I simply want to be able to update the list of Branch Filters under a Pipelines trigger through the API.

The answer is yes.

You could use the REST API [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to update the triggers.

Using the REST API [Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) we could to know the branchFilters is array so we could not just edit it, you need to edit the `triggers[0]`, the same thing as `triggers`:

[image]

Now, we could use following powershell scripts to invoke REST API to update the trigger:

```
$connectionToken="Your PAT here."
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/<YourOrganization>/<YourProject>/_apis/build/definitions/139?api-version=6.0" 

$pipelineInfo = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})

Write-Host "TriggerInfo= $($pipelineInfo.triggers[0].branchFilters[0] | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

#update the branch trigger from "master" to "Dev1"

$pipelineInfo.triggers[0].branchFilters[0] = "+refs/heads/Dev1"

$body = $pipelineInfo | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99

$updateTrigger = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $body -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

The test result:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this! I will give it a go in a bit and update accordingly!

Comment: @CJH, You are always welcome :). If you have any update, please let me know for free. Have a nice day!

Comment: Just to be a real pain, would you happen to be able to supply the example code in C# please? If not, I will see if I can transcribe it :)

Comment: @CJH, Sorry, I didn’t use C# to write such a sample, but you could check the sample from this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205058/retrieve-the-list-of-tasks-for-build-definition-using-net-client-libraries-for

Comment: Hey, sorry I had meant to come back to this but been hectic at home the last week. The piece of work I was doing was no longer required before I could attempt your suggestion - and therefore am not able to confirm if it is "correct". Im thinking I see from your screenshot however that it looks like it has worked so on that basis will mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: @CJH, Thanks for your reply and confirm. If you have any follow-up questions about this issue, please let me know for free, I will keep follow. Have a nice day!